# Redirect a form according to the clicked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to redirect the user to different pages according to checkboxes they have clicked.

Here is the scenario:

I have got 9 checkboxes of which 3 has its own URL to redirect and if checked in combination they also have a different URL to redirect too. For example, if checkbox **a** is clicked redirect to its default URL, but if **a+b** is clicked redirect to a diff one and so on for checkbox c also. So I have got 7 pages that the user needs to be redirected to **a,b,c,a+b+c, a+ba+c,b+c** and if other check boxes have been clicked they can just be redirected to a default thank you page (**e** is clicked redirect to the default page, **a+e** is clicked redirect to a's page). This needs to happen when the form is submitted.

By far I have been able to get the value of each checked box when clicking the submit button but I am completely lost on how to proceed further.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
$("#send-a").click(function() {
        var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
             return this.value;
        }).get();
        console.log(checkedValues);return false;

    });
```

Comment: Is this really a "php" question?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i figured this problem could be solved by on either client-side or the server-side.

Comment: I see. Ok thanks. Well, for a php serverside method, all you'd need to do is use `isset()` with a conditional statement and then using a redirection method of choice. Edit: I'd use a radio instead of a checkbox though.

Comment: In contrast to @FunkFortyNiner proposal, I wouldn't use a radio (group) because of UX. A user expects to only select one of the radios whereas in case of a checkbox, multiple combinations are possible. This is how a radio button group behaves as well.

Comment: @twisted-dev Does my answer below solve your problem?

Comment: @Johannes Thing is with a checkbox, one would have to prevent people from selecting more than one checkbox. You can't redirect to multiple URL's.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner If I understood @twisted-dev correctly, (s)he actually wants to retrieve ONE redirect based on one or MULTIPLE selected checkboxes (`a,b,c,a+b+c, a+ba+c,b+c`). E.g. selecting checkbox `a` and `c` redirects to `abc.html`, selecting only `a` redirects to `another_page.html` instead.

Comment: @Johannes Hard to say but you could be right. I am not a JS guy, so I couldn't elaborate on that. I'm mostly serverside. I Google the JS stuff when I need it ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The logic should be the same. My answer below represents my understanding of the question, maybe twisted-dev will give a hint if this goes to the right direction. In case your assumption is right it can be easily changed to radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could concatenate the values of the selected checkboxes using e.g. `toString()` (comma as separator) and use a `switch` to check the combination after sorting the array. I'm assuming the values of the checkbox being `a`, `b` and `c`.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    // sort in alphabetical order
    checkedValue = checkedValues.sort();

    var valueString = checkedValues.toString();
    switch(valueString) {
        case 'a':
            // redirect to A
            break;
        case 'b':
            // redirect to B
            break;
        case 'a,b':
            // redirect to A+B
            break;
        // other combinations, check for letters separated by comma
        default:
            // default redirect               
    }                
});
```

Comment: @twisted-dev Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. This helps other users to find solutions faster!

Comment: sorry for the late reply yes this did solve my problem I made a few modifications myself but your logic was very helpful. thanks